# Multiple upload picture to mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
include('../connect.php');
$id=$_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM discharge WHERE id='$id'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo '<img src=../'.$row['ppic'].' style="float:left; margin-right:10px;">';
    echo '<img src=../'.$row['ppic1'].' style="float:left; margin-right:10px;">';
    }
?>
<form action="editpicexec.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <br>
    <input type="hidden" name="roomid" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>">
    Select Image
    <br>
    <input type="file" name="image[]" multiple="multiple" /><br>
    <input type="file" name="image1"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

`discharge` is my table database, I want to add picture multiple at in one input.
in this code I am opening a file one at a time, but I want to add multiple picture and then save in the field on the database

```
<?php
include('../connect.php');
    if (!isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "";
    }else
    $file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
    $image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $image_size= getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);


            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"../images/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);

            $location="images/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
            $roomid=$_POST['roomid'];

            if(!$update=mysql_query("UPDATE discharge SET ppic = '$location' WHERE id='$roomid'"))


                if (!isset($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "";
    }else
    $file=$_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'];
    $image1= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']));
    $image1_name= addslashes($_FILES['image1']['name']);
    $image1_size= getimagesize($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);


            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image1"]["tmp_name"],"../images/" . $_FILES["image1"]["name"]);

            $location="images/" . $_FILES["image1"]["name"];
            $roomid=$_POST['roomid'];

            if(!$update=mysql_query("UPDATE discharge SET ppic1 = '$location' WHERE id='$roomid'"))
?>
```

Then this is my process I dont know how can I upload on database in single input with many pictures . `ppic` and `ppic1` is the name of my field on my database.

Comment: You should really stop using mysql_* and convert over to mysqli_ or PDO

Comment: Explain better what's going on

Answer (score 0):

if I understood your question right. You might want to use foreach to go through all file in image input like this:

```
    foreach ($_FILES['image'] as $one_file){
    $file=$one_file['tmp_name'];
     // rest of code 
     // in the case you want to save all path in same field, change the line bellow like this
     // if(!$update=mysql_query("UPDATE discharge SET ppic = concat(ppic, '$location' )  WHERE id='$roomid'"))
    }
    ?>
```

Instead of `concat(ppic, '$location' )` you can use `CONCAT_WS(',', ppic, '$location')` to separate it by comma.